# Убрать ссылку в модальном окне без последствий

Tags: html, css, wordpress, всплывающее-окно

Всем привет! Добавляю в сайт на wordpress всплывающее модальное окно с формой обратной связи с помощью visual composer и скрипта magnific popup. Сам код:

```html
<a class="popup-modal btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#modal-event">Заказать</a>
<div id="modal-event" class="white-popup mfp-hide">
  <h3>Бриф</h3>
  [contact-form-7 id="3155" title="Форма по ивентам"]
  <a class="popup-modal-dismiss" href="#">Закрыть</a>
</div>
```

Хочу избавиться от ссылки с надписью закрыть, но если ее просто удалить - вся форма уползает с модального окна на страницу и в нем остается только заголовок Бриф.. Что посоветуете?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`style="display: none;"` возможно поможет.

Comment: да, спасибо помогло, но ведь это костыль...

Comment: Это не костыль. Хотя правильнее в css файле сделать:

Comment: нашел правильное решение! Надо удалять не из visual composer, а переключиться на классический редактор и уже из него - тогда все норм удаляется